# How to use CUDA_FORCE_PTX_JIT?

Tags: linux, cuda, nvcc

According to NVIDIA Programming Guide:

> Any PTX code loaded by an application at runtime is compiled further
>   to binary code by the device driver. This is called just-in-time
>   compilation. Just-in-time compilation increases application load time,
>   but allows applications to benefit from latest compiler improvements.

...

> Setting CUDA_FORCE_PTX_JIT to 1 forces the device driver to ignore any
>   binary code embedded in an application (see Section 3.1.4) and to
>   just-in-time compile embedded PTX code instead; if a kernel does not
>   have embedded PTX code, it will fail to load

I've compiled my simple vectorAdd using following flags:

```
nvcc -o vectorAdd -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 vectorAdd.cu
```

When the `CUDA_FORCE_PTX_JIT` environment variable is unset, I get correct results. But when I set the `CUDA_FORCE_PTX_JIT` environment variable to `1` I get following error from `cudaGetErrorString`:

```
invalid device function
```

How can I fix this issue and get CUDA_FORCE_PTX_JIT working? Maybe the way of my compilation does not embed any PTX code.

Thanks in Advance.

***Further information:***

CUDA Driver Version: 295.41

CUDA Toolkit version: 4.0

OS: Ubuntu 10.04

Hardware: GTX 480, or Tesla C2050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround to handle the issue. During compile, the target GPU must not be specified in anyway (Remove `-arch` or `-gencode` flags). Subsequently, the driver generates the destination binary at the runtime.